# PHP - "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object error"

Tags: php, xml

I'm getting this 'Notice:Trying to get property of non-object error"...

I have currently this varDump:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["ASIN"]=>
      string(10) "0747587086"
      ["status"]=>
      string(7) "Success"
    }
    ["Product"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
      ["Identifiers"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
        ["MarketplaceASIN"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (2) {
          ["MarketplaceId"]=>
          string(13) "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
          ["ASIN"]=>
          string(10) "0747587086"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my call for the xml elemtn that gives the error:

```
echo $xmlFile->GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult->Identifier->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN. "\n";
```

Could anyone advise on what I need to do? I've done some research online; but it seems case specific...

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for formatting Barmar!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You skipped `Product`, and you left out the `s` at the end of `Identifiers`. It should be

```
$xmlFile->GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult->Product->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN
```

Comment: Both you and Dan got the same answer..
Thank you for catching my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it needs to be `$xmlFile->GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult->Product->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN`